# Swift struct for constants

Tags: swift, memory-management, constants

1. What does `final` mean inside a struct definition?
2. Should it be added to the struct it in the below case?
3. Is it a good idea (performance, memory considerations, etc.) to use a struct for constants?
4. Should it be called `Constant` or `Constants`?

Example:

```
final struct Constant { 
    static let cellId = "CellId"
}
```

Comment: This will not compile at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. `final` is a modifier that prevents a class from being inherited, and a class method or class property from being overridden - it is not applicable to structs (because inheritance is not available), and the compiler should throw an error message. Described in [Preventing Overrides](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-ID202)
2. see (1)
3. I prefer to use structs because classes do not support static stored properties (yet). I don't think there's any difference between using a class or a struct, as long as constant properties are declared as static - however, if class is the choice, it's a good idea to use `final`.
4. Your choice :) I'd use `Constants`, unless the struct is for just one constant only

Answer (score 0):

As Apple says (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html) the final is to prevent methods/properties to be overwritten. So you can not create a superclass that changes the element.

Calling it Constant or Constants? I guess it depends on the number of properties inside the struct.

If you try your example in Playground it will simply not compile.